# Liferay: How can I get the pages of the site in a web content?

Tags: liferay, velocity

I have a portal in Liferay 6.2, and need to design the velocity template of a web content that must have a menu listing the pages (linked names) of the site where is present.

My questions are:

- Is this possible?
- What would be the correct way to do this?
- Would it be better to make a portlet instead of a web content for this purpose?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Having custom portlet would be better idea for your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

It feels a bit like you are trying to solve many problems in a single template - consider to compose the UI from many different elements (e.g. custom portlets) rather than building the one structure/template that fits all requirements.

That being said, as there's also the chance that your template doesn't do more than just displaying the current navigation: You have two options: The out-of-the-box Navigation portlet is quite configurable, you might be able to utilize that one instead of implementing anything yourself (check the configuration options).

And lastly, if you want to implement for yourself: Get hold of the [themeDisplay](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/theme/ThemeDisplay.html) object. With `getLayout()` you'll get the current page, while `getLayouts()` you'll get all pages of the current site and can enumerate them. However, there's one problem: You typically don't have access to the `themeDisplay` object from a CMS template. But there are several ways to still get to the data (search the Liferay forums for *cms template themedisplay*). Also, an Application Display Template will be a lot more powerful - and you can also check how the `layouts` collection is built - just search for usage of `ThemeDisplay.setLayouts` in Liferay's source code. But with ADT we're diverting from your original question.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer Olaf, but (whether I like it or not) making a web content for this is an actual requirement. I´m working on the solution using your indications. If I sort this out, will let you know. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

Liferay offers a sitemap portlet out-of-the-box which lists pages of a site. You can configure it and define your own application display template (ADT).

Comment: Thanks for answering! As I told Olaf, making a web content for this is a requirement, so my hands are quite tied concerning this.